# What is the logic of sample_n command (replace=TRUE)?

Tags: r, dplyr, sample

I am confused about the logic of `sample_n` command (for `replace=TRUE` case) in dplyr package. I am using `sample_n` but I could not figure out how are my samples replicated, what is the logic behind it?

As I look to the sampled data, the fractions or specific ratios between the variables were not conserved.

Comment: What do you mean with `logic`? To generate a replicable randomized process, you typically use `set.seed()`.

Answer (score 6):

`dplyr::sample_n` calls `sample.int`, so we'll look into that. Imagine you have a sack containing 10 ping pong balls, numbered sequentially.

- `sample(..., replace=FALSE)` means you reach into the sack and pull out a ping-pong ball, record the number, and set it aside. You are assured that the number you just picked can not be pulled out of the sack again. Using this method, you can at most randomly select 10 balls (where the last one pulled should be certainty of its impending value).
- `sample(..., replace=TRUE)` means you reach into the sack, pull out a ping-pong ball, record the number, then put the ball back into the sack. It is feasible that your next reach into the sack could pull out the same ball. Using this method, you can pull (many) more than 10 balls out of the sack, recognizing that you may have repeats when 10 or fewer balls are pulled, and certainly will have repeats when you have pulled more than 10.